# Is Robocasting Development in Ceramic Multimaterial Deposition Prior Art? US20100327479 A1

Tags: prior-art-request, prior-art, pre-grant, us20100327479

Is the following document "Robocasting Development in Robocasting of Ceramic Multimaterial Deposition" Prior Art?

As it seems to cover the same points as patent US20100327479 A1 but was published some time in the 1990's.

http://utwired.engr.utexas.edu/lff/symposium/proceedingsArchive/pubs/Manuscripts/1998/1998-80-Cesarano.pdf

Claim 1 of the '479 application:

> 1. A compounding system for forming a customized consumable material, the compounding system comprising:
>
>    a controller configured to operably receive a user input related to one or more user-selected material characteristics;
>
>    a plurality of drive mechanisms configured to operably communicate with the controller, and further configured to **feed a plurality of stock materials at independent feed rates** that are determined based at least in part upon the user input; and
>
>    an extrusion component configured to receive the plurality of fed stock materials, and further configured to at **least partially melt and blend the received stock materials to provide the customized consumable materia**l in an extrudable state, wherein upon solidifying the customized consumable material exhibits the one or more user-selected material characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

The dates of the references would technically allow it to be cited as prior art but a quick look through the paper doesn't show anything about multiple feeds of material at different rates that are blended together in a user-adjustable ratio. An the patent does not seem to be about ceramic material, the subject of the paper.